React Query keep query data between navigation
I'm having a little issue with react query, the issue is that once i redirect to a new page the query refetches the data even with the ( in theory ) right settings.
Let me explain better.....
I have this page called

/signup/result-callbak?result-id=some-uuid-code

All i do on this page is just call the query set the response into a store ( i need to do that for other purposes ) and do a redirect depending on the results
export default function Page() {
  /*--------------------hooks--------------------*/
  const router = useNavigation()
  const { data } = useSignupdataQuery()
  const { setData } = useSignupStepsStore()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!data) return

    setData(data.okResponse.payload)

    if (data.initialErrorPath) return router.push(data.initialErrorPath)

    router.push("/signup/access-data")

  }, [data, setData, router])

  return <Loader />
}

The query looks like this:
const useSignupdataQuery = () => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams()
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["get-data"],
    refetchOnMount: false,
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    refetchOnReconnect: false,
    staleTime: Infinity,
    gcTime: Infinity,
    queryFn: () =>
      dataFetcher({
        resultId: searchParams.get("result-id") as string,
      }),
  })
}

( Yes that result-id is preserved in the search params when i redirect )
Now the problem is that when i reach the new page and call
const { data } = useSignupdataQuery()

again for some reason it refetches the data, now i understand from the docs that when the query unmounts if the staletime expired and the gc kicks in it cleans the data up and it does the refetch but it does that even if i put infinity as staletime / gctime.....am i doing something wrong here ?

It just turned out that i'm a clown
I had this configuration for the query client
  const queryClient = new QueryClient({
    queryCache: new QueryCache({
      onError,
    }),
    mutationCache: new MutationCache({
      onError,
    }),
    defaultOptions: {
      queries: {
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      },
    },
  })

But it sits below the react router so every time i redirect it creates a new one as it sits in a react component
Editing into this fixed the problem
  const [queryClient] = useState(
    new QueryClient({
      queryCache: new QueryCache({
        onError,
      }),
      mutationCache: new MutationCache({
        onError,
      }),
      defaultOptions: {
        queries: {
          refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        },
      },
    })
  )

